# How to properly export CALayer on top of AVMutableComposition with AVAssetExportSession

Tags: iphone, core-animation, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition, avassetexportsession

I know this question was asked before (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997677/mix-video-with-static-image-in-calayer-using-avvideocompositioncoreanimationtool) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206839/how-to-use-avmutablecomposition-and-calayers-on-ios)) but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have an `AVMutableComposition` that I use to combine some video clips with some `CALayer`s that animate on top of them.

Everything works ok when I take my `AVMutableComposition` and combine it with an `AVSynchronizedLayer` for playback inside an `AVPlayerLayer`. The video comes out correctly and everything is positioned where it should.

My problem is that when I tried to export this thing I tried using `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` instead of `AVSynchronizedLayer` (that's what the documentation says we should use for export) and an AVAssetExportSession, but something goes wrong because in my exported movie every `CALayer` has it's coordinate system reversed.

So if during playback the the 0,0 point is in the **top-left** corner of the screen when I export the movie the 0,0 point is in the **bottom-left** corner hence my animation go nuts.

I read any possible article about this and I also downloaded AVVideoEdit sample from Apple but I just can't see what is going on...

Comment: If you ever get an answer I'm interested.

Comment: I never found a good answer for this. What I did was just before the export I pass the layer that holds the animation to a custom function I wrote that goes trough all sublayers recursively and changes the coordinates... It's kind of a hack and an ugly solution but it did the trick for me.

Comment: could you provide some code? I'm trying to do the same stuff and can't get it done :(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For anyone who has the same problem as I had I've finally found an answer. There is a property of every `CALayer` called `geometryFlipped` wich you need to set to `YES` just before exporting and everything will be ok. More information [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/geometryFlipped).

Comment: why is this necessary?

Answer (score -1):

```
Methods that fixing frames and points
- (CGRect) fixRect:(CGRect)rect inRect:(CGRect)container
{
    CGRect frame = rect;
    frame.origin.y = container.size.height - frame.origin.y - frame.size.height;
    return frame;
}
- (CGPoint) fixPoint:(CGPoint)point fromPoint:(CGSize)containerSize
{
    CGPoint frame = point;
    frame.y = containerSize.height - frame.y;
    return frame;
}
```