# AVSynchronizedLayer doesn't match AVAssetExportSession output, Why?

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avassetwriter, avcomposition

The problem is this: I have a AVMutableVideoComposition which has a titleLayer (CATextLayer).

I want to display to the user a preview containing this title, using AVPlayerLayer and AVSynchronizedLayer. I setup the layer like this:

```
    - (CATextLayer*)buildTitleLayer {
    CATextLayer *titleLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
    // titleLayer.font = @"Helvetica";
    titleLayer.fontSize = 15.0;
    //?? titleLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    titleLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
    titleLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _videoSize.width, _videoSize.height / 6); //You may need to adjust this for proper display
    return  titleLayer;
}
```

When I setup the composition I do this:

```
    [compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:clipVideoTrack.preferredTransform];
```

Everything runs as expected with one exception:

When I preview the end result (video+title) in the iPhone simulator I get this output:

[image: Notice the Hello Video Label on black background on the top of the view]

When I render the video using AVAssetExportSession I get this output (so the video label is on the bottom):

[image: Notice the Hello Video Label on the bottom]

Does anyone know what is the trick? What am I missing/doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found here

[How to properly export CALayer on top of AVMutableComposition with AVAssetExportSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749216/how-to-properly-export-calayer-on-top-of-avmutablecomposition-with-avassetexport)