# How to scale CALayer to fit on the video layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiview

I have a problem with CALayer. The point is that I want to save few UIViews on the movie. Basically I am trying to do it by CALayer. Everything is okay, the app export movie with layers but the layers with views are smaller than video frame.

I tried to scale layer manually but at all it is not look like on the screen. If I move UIView higher on movie it is going much higher.

Video has FullHd frame and layers of UIView depends of it how user place it on the screen.

**The questions are:**
- How to render UIView Context with better retina quality?

- How to scale layers to fit perfectly to the video.

There is the code:

```
VideoSaver.saveVideo(videoAsset!) { (composition, size) in
        ////////////////
        //Parent Layer//
        ////////////////

        let parentLayer = CALayer()
        parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)

        /////////
        //Sizes//
        /////////
        let xScaleValue = CGRectGetWidth(parentLayer.frame)/CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)
        let yScaleValue = CGRectGetHeight(parentLayer.frame)/CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)

        ///////////////
        //Video Layer//
        ///////////////
        let videoLayer = CALayer()
        videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)

        //////////////////
        //Captions Layer//
        //////////////////

        //Creating UIImage from Captions
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.captionsTextView.bounds.size.width, self.captionsTextView.bounds.size.height+20))
        let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, 16)

        self.captionsTextView.layer.renderInContext(currentContext!)
        let captionTextViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        let captionsOverlayLayer = CALayer()
        captionsOverlayLayer.contents = captionTextViewImage.CGImage
        captionsOverlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(self.captionsTextView.frame.origin.x * xScaleValue,
                                            (size.height - ((self.captionsTextView.frame.origin.y - 20) * yScaleValue)),
                                            CGRectGetWidth(self.captionsTextView.frame) * xScaleValue,
                                            (CGRectGetHeight(self.captionsTextView.frame)+20) * yScaleValue)

        captionsOverlayLayer.masksToBounds = true

        ///////////////////
        //TagFilter Layer//
        ///////////////////
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.tagView.bounds.size)
        self.tagView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

        let tagViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        let tagOverlayLayer = CALayer()
        tagOverlayLayer.contents = tagViewImage.CGImage
        tagOverlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(self.tagView.frame.origin.x * xScaleValue,
                                           (size.height - ((self.tagView.frame.origin.y) * yScaleValue)),
                                           CGRectGetWidth(self.tagView.frame) * xScaleValue,
                                           (CGRectGetHeight(self.tagView.frame)) * yScaleValue)
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////

        parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
        parentLayer.addSublayer(captionsOverlayLayer)
        parentLayer.addSublayer(tagOverlayLayer)

        ///////////////
        //Composition//
        ///////////////
        composition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool.init(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, inLayer: parentLayer)
    }
```

I will be glad for help :)

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is the *resolution* of the image as displayed by the layer, then:

- This is your first mistake: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`. Always call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and a third argument of `0`, or an explicit resolution.
- Your second mistake is that you never set the CALayer's `contentsScale`.

Comment: If I understand correctly I must add to every CALayer `contentScale = self.myView.layer.contentsScale`? I changed also `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(self.captionsTextView.bounds.size.width, self.captionsTextView.bounds.size.height+20),
                                                   false,
                                                   0.0)`. Unfortunately I do not know how to resize layers to the video size :(

Comment: Well, the thing you're doing has been thoroughly covered here; see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997677/mix-video-with-static-image-in-calayer-using-avvideocompositioncoreanimationtool, and also tutorials like https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Answer (score 1):

At the end all `UIViews` that I want to have on the video I put to one `UIView`. From that `UIView` I am creating the layer and scaling it to video size. There is a code if someone will have the same problem:

```
VideoSaver.saveVideo(videoAsset!) 
{ 
    (composition, size) in
    ////////////////
    //Parent Layer//
    ////////////////

    let parentLayer = CALayer()
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)

    ///////////////
    //Video Layer//
    ///////////////
    let videoLayer = CALayer()
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)

    ///////////////////////
    //Effect Layout Layer//
    ///////////////////////
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.effectLayoutView.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    self.effectLayoutView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

    let effectLayoutViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    let effectOverlayLayer = CALayer()
    effectOverlayLayer.contents = effectLayoutViewImage.CGImage

    effectOverlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
    effectOverlayLayer.masksToBounds = true

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(effectOverlayLayer)

    ///////////////
    //Composition//
    ///////////////
    composition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool.init(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, inLayer: parentLayer)
}
```

Comment: i am experiencing same  problem, sub layer of parent layer not getting resized according to video layer size. Can you please help me ? and you have added  parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(effectOverlayLayer)  why ?