# Downscale CALayer proportionally and add to UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, calayer

I need to convert a CALayer with frame `{{0, 0}, {656, 656}}` and display it in a UIView which has frame `{{0, 0}, {320, 480}}`

```
layer.bounds = view.bounds;
layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill;
layer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(view.bounds));
```

What I see is `kCAGravityResizeAspectFill` stretches the layer content in height and `kCAGravityResizeAspect` stretches the video in width. How do I scale it down proportionally and display in the UI?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37550294/how-to-scale-calayer-to-fit-on-the-video-layer).

Looks like you are most likely having issues with your *content* size rather than the layers rendering.

It also greatly depends on what *your* preference is. Would you like the content to "fit" or "fill" the new view?

Quite simply, instead of passing the `CALayer` the bounds of the desired display view, give it a frame of either

1. the height of the view and allow it to clip the sides `{480, 480}` and center, or
2. the width of the view {320, 320} and deal with it *not* filling the top / bottom of the view.

> I am assuming here that the scale / aspect ratio of the layer is indeed a square, as you have stated it's size is 656x656.

Regardless, depending on the content mode you pass to your layer it should from here adjust appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `kCAGravityResizeAspect` instead of `kCAGravityResizeAspectFill`. It will scale the layer to show the *entire* layer while maintaining its aspect ratio (and it centers it at the same time).

This is an example, using a `656x656` image to demonstrate:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"656x656"];

CALayer *layer = [CALayer new];
layer.frame = _theView.bounds;
layer.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)([img CGImage]);

layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect;

[_theView.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: as I have mentioned in my post I have tried both kCAGravityResizeAspect and kCAGravityResizeAspectFill

Comment: @Neelesh - well, that image is what I got with that code... If that's not what you're getting, show a screen-cap of your results?